# Div not expanding to fill the window

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to find a solution to this for days, but haven't found anything that works.
I thought I'd finally make an account on this great website, so here goes:

I am trying to have a div expand from left to right, with 170px of clearance on both sides.
However, when there is no content on the page, or only a few words, the div doesn't expand. 
I've tried to add width: 100% in several different divs to try and have them take up the full space, but that either does nothing, or completely busts the page layout. for example, instead of filling out the page, the div that's supposed to hold the content moves off the right side of the screen, and also doesn't leave the 170px margin.

I hope you can be of help, my code is posted below:
Thanks in advance,
Chris

the html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="pagetopwrap">
    </div>
    <div id="pagemainliquid">
        <div id="pagemainwrap">
            <div id="content">

                <div id="headerwrap">
                    <div id="header_left">
                    </div>
                    <div id="header_main">
                        <div id="logo_row">
                            <p id="logotext">Site Title</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu_row">
                            <!-- irrelevant menu button code -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="header_right">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="contentbody">
                    <div id="contenttext">
                        <p id="contenttextmakeup">Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leftcolumnwrap">
        <div id="leftcolumn">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightcolumnwrap">
        <div id="rightcolumn">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footerwrap">
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the css:
It is not ordered too well, the uninteresting sides, top and footer are first, and the main part of the website at the bottom

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #0f0f0f; /* is normally an image */
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%
}

#pagetopwrap {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


#pagemainliquid {
    float: left;
}

#pagemainwrap {
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-right: 170px;
    float: left;
}

#leftcolumnwrap {
    width: 170px;
    margin-left:-100%;
    float: left;
}

#leftcolumn {
    margin: 5px;
}

#rightcolumnwrap {
    width: 170px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    float: left;
}

#rightcolumn {
    margin: 5px;
}

#footerwrap {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    bottom:50px;
}

#footer {
    height: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#headerwrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header_left {
    background-color: #ff0000; /* is normally an image */
    width:25px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
}
#header_right {
    background-color: #ff0000; /* is normally an image */
    width:25px;
    height:200px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float:right;
    position:relative; top:-200px;
}
#header_main {
    background-color: #00ff00; /* is normally an image */
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    height:200px;
    background-size: 100% 200px; 
}
#contentbody {
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border: 1px solid #A7A7B2;
}
#contenttext {
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#logo_row {
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
#logotext {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Arial;
}
#contenttextmakeup {
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-left:10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#menu_row {
    width:100%;
}
button.menubutton {
/* irrelevant button markup */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w9qLh6tp/ if that helps, I've seen it a lot around here :)

Comment: if div is 100% of it's parent, the body, then it won't be very tall. try setting body to have a height.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/w9qLh6tp/3/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using !important, save yourself a headache in figuring out why important works.

CSS = cascading style sheets. You have a selector with more specificity which is why your width property isnt changing. Figuring out the route of the problem will save you time in the future when this happens again (and it will)

For example, if I styled something like so

```
#container .red { width: 50% }
```

updating the style using .red without the #container in front of it has less specificity. So if they are both modifying the same property, the one with more prevalence will take effect. This is true for media queries as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I probably have an error in my css somewhere... I might need to build it from the ground up again, but maybe I'll make the same mistake

Comment: Take a look at SASS/SCSS. You can nest your CSS and it makes this type of problem happen less often.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed here http://jsfiddle.net/w9qLh6tp/1/

```
 #pagemainwrap {
        margin-left: 170px;
        margin-right: 170px;
        float: left;
        width: 100% !important; // set it highest priority
        border: 3px red solid; // border is set just for demonstration
    }
```

set the width to be 100% with priority (!important) that will override any other css styling.

Comment: This still doesn't make the right side of the website conform to the 170px margin, it actually makes the width fixed for some reason, have you got any idea why? Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: how much margin is it acquiring then?

Comment: I've actually tested this on my own browser (chrome) and internet explorer. on the left side, it adheres to the 170px margin, but on the right side, it seems to do whatever it seems fit. It still expands out of the right side of the screen, making a scroll bar appear, and then has a +/- 100px margin. on the other hand, when I expand my browser window to be way bigger than my screen, it actually has 0 margin on the right.